# c# search index of combobox by object

Tags: c#, search, combobox, indexof

Good morning experts,

I have a combobox which gets filled with class type values.

My class name is Cars.

```
public string Description;
public long Id;
```

My function to load the combobox is

```
foreach(Cars car in CarList)
{
comboCars.Items.Add(car);
}
```

I have a function that needs to search a car in that combobox, I have this code.

```
public void setCarCmb(long id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < comboCars.Items.Count; i++)
    {
      if (((Cars)comboCars.Items[i]).Id == id)
      {
        comboCars.SelectedIndex = i;
        comboCars.Enabled = false;
        break;
      }
     }
}
```

Which works, but I'm trying to find a better and faster way, I tried using

```
public void setCarCmb(Cars car)
{
  comboCars.SelectedIndex = comboCars.Items.IndexOf(car);
  comboCars.Enabled = false;
}
```

But the index returned is always -1, what seems to be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
comboCars.SelectedIndex = comboCars.Items.IndexOf(car);
```

tries to find the index of the `car` object in your combo box items. However, simply because two objects have the same property values, doesn't mean they are the same object. Take the following example for instance.

```
Car car1 = new Car() { Id = 1, Description = "MyCar" };
Car car2 = new Car() { Id = 1, Description = "MyCar" };
bool equality = car1 == car2;
```

This code will return `false`, because although the contents of those two objects are the same, they are still two different objects.

Same thing happens with your `IndexOf()` comparison, and since it can't find the object you're passing in the combo box, it returns `-1` which means 'no match'.

### NOTE:

The way you're looking for the object in the working example is just fine.

### NOTE 2:

If you really want to use a method like `SetCarCmb`, you can implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface in your `Car` class like this:

```
public class Car : IEquatable<Car>
{
    public string Description;
    public long Id;

    public bool Equals(Car other)
    {
        // Choose what you want to consider as "equal" between Car objects. 
        // For example, equality of ID means two objects are equal in this example.
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return Id == other.Id;
    }
}
```

Now instead of comparing two object references, the `IndexOf()` method will use this comparer to compare two objects of `Car` class. So you'll modify your method like this:

```
public static void SetCarCmb(Car car)
{
    comboCars.SelectedIndex = comboCars.Items.Cast<Car>().ToList().IndexOf(car);
    comboCars.Enabled = false;
}
```

But really, there's no need to go into all this trouble. Your first method should work just fine, especially considering it's highly unlikely that a combo box will contain thousands of items, and that efficiency shouldn't really be a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your second method isn't working is because the `IndexOf` method is doing a ***reference*** comparison between the car you're passing as an argument and the cars in the combo box, and it isn't finding an exact match (a reference comparison means that both objects refer to the same location in memory).

The only way your new method will work in it's current form is if you pass in a car from the `CarsList` (which are the same cars that the combo box is bound to).

If you want to be able to pass in other cars that have the same Id (and/or Description) and have them match, then you'll need to override the `Equals` method so that it only compares these fields (instead of doing a reference comparison) so that `IndexOf` will work:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // Consider any other car whose Id is the same as this car to be equal
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Car;
        return other?.Id == Id; // optionally add: && other.Description == Description;
    }
}
```

After this change, your new method should work as expected.